# android viewpager change adapter

Tags: android, adapter, android-viewpager

I'm developing an app with a ViewPager for lateral scrolling tables, sometimes i need to change the adapter to load a different set of tables.
I've tried to do the following:

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(new pagerAdapterPushed(getSupportFragmentManager()));
mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
indicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
indicator.invalidate();
mViewPager.invalidate();
```

but it always reload the previous data. Isn't it possibile to change the adapter of a ViewPager?

Answer (score 34):

Exactly like my APP doing...

For change ViewPagerAdapter, what I did is :

1. Clear all Fragments inside current adapter
2. Set current adapter to null
3. Assign new adpater for ViewPager

   ```
   /* Clear all Fragments inside current adapter */
   public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
   {
     private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
     //...some stuff

     public void clearAll() //Clear all page
     {
       for(int i = 0; i < fragments.size(); i ++)
       fragMan.beginTransaction().remove(fragments.get(i)).commit();
       fragments.clear();
     }
   }

   /* Set current adapter to null */
   Constants.VP.removeAllViews();
   Constants.VP.setAdapter(null);

   /* Assign new adpater for ViewPager */
   Constants.PAGER = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
   Constants.VP.setAdapter(Constants.PAGER);
   ```

Hope it helps~

Comment: I tried your solution. It work perfect without any issues. thanks a lot

Comment: In API 18 I couldn't `setAdapter(null)`. However everything else worked. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been looking for this for some days now!

Comment: For me, the only necessary part was removing the fragments using fragment manager transactions.  The rest was unnecessary (i.e. removeAllViews, setAdapter(null), etc).

Comment: For some reason this only worked for me after I changed it from FragmentPagerAdapter to FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Answer (score 3):

You need to override `public int getItemPosition (Object object)` in pager adapter.  For every element in the viewpager, you need to return `POSITION_UNCHANGED` (if it is still in the pager) or `POSITION_NONE` (if it was removed).  Otherwise the view pager won't know something has changed.  I wouldn't recommend setting a new adapter, just clearing out the data in the old one.

Answer (score 3):

I see that @RRTW way worked for some people but it did not do the trick for me (although it was close). Without `commitNow()` instead of regular `commit()` it would not work properly. I did something like that:

```
private fun changePagerAdapter(newAdapter: PagerAdapter) {

    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        supportFragmentManager.fragments.forEach {
        transaction.remove(it)
    }

    transaction.commitNow()
    view_pager.adapter = newAdapter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who still have issues, do like what I did. I wish it will save your time. It is in Xamarin.Android, but idea should be same in java and kotlin

Prepare your Adapter classes with ClearFragments method through an abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseAdapter : FragmentStateAdapter
{
    public BaseAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Lifecycle lifecycle) : base(fm, lifecycle)
    {
        this.fm = fm;
    }
    readonly FragmentManager fm;
    
    public override int ItemCount => ITEM_COUNT;

    private readonly List<Fragment> fragments = new List<Fragment>();
    
    
    public override Fragment CreateFragment(int position)
    {
        var fragment = new MyFragment();
        fragments.Add(fragment);
        return fragment;
    }
    
    public void ClearFragments()
    {
        if (fragments.Count > 0)
        {
            var transaction = fm.BeginTransaction();
            foreach (var fragment in fragments)
            {
                transaction.Remove(fragment);
            }
            if (!fm.IsDestroyed)
            {
                transaction.CommitNow();
            }
            //see note of Dispose(disposing)
            foreach (var fragment in fragments)
            {
                fragment.Dispose();
            }
            fragments.Clear();
        }
    }
    
    private bool disposedValue = false;
    
    //Important note: Your fragment might use Context. You need to override Dispose(disposing) in your fragment class
    //and ensure you do not use Context after you dispose it here
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            disposedValue = true;
            if (disposing)
            {
                ClearFragments();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}

public Adapter1 : BaseAdapter
{
    public Adapter1(FragmentManager fm, Lifecycle lifecycle) : base(fm, lifecycle)
    {
        
    }
}

public Adapter2 : BaseAdapter
{
    public Adapter2(FragmentManager fm, Lifecycle lifecycle) : base(fm, lifecycle)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Then when you want to change adapter, do like this:

```
public MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private void UseAdapter2()
    {
        var oldAdapter = viewPager.Adapter as BaseAdapter;
        oldAdapter?.ClearFragments();
        viewPager.Adapter = null;
        var adapter = new Adapter2(SupportFragmentManager, Lifecycle);
        // Do any logic that makes this adapter different from the previous one.
        viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
        oldAdapter?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ibrahim
Your recommendation goes against the advice of the ViewPager2 docs. It specifically states do not use that technique for CreateFragment. You must always return a new instance of a fragment. Do not reuse from a list of fragments.
See https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration

Answer (score -5):

Add this to view pager to reload for next fragment:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem()
```