# App crashes when assigning new adapter to my ViewPager

Tags: android, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a `ViewPager` which is populated by a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` when the app starts:

```
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new PageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        //PageAdapter extends from FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    }
```

This works fine as it should.

Now, when the user changes the settings of the app I'd like to assign a new Adapter to the ViewPager like this:

```
@Override
public void updateObserver(SETTING_KEY key) 
{
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new PageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    Log.d("info", "updating");
}
```

Unfortunately the app crashes after calling `updateObserver` with this exception:

> 01-22 23:22:45.957: E/AndroidRuntime(13131): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-22 23:22:45.957: E/AndroidRuntime(13131): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragement no longer exists for key f0: index 0
>   01-22 23:22:45.957: E/AndroidRuntime(13131):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:575)
>   01-22 23:22:45.957: E/AndroidRuntime(13131):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:211)
>   01-22 23:22:45.957: E/AndroidRuntime(13131):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1281)
>   01-22 23:22:45.957: E/AndroidRuntime(13131):    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:13188)
>   01-22 23:22:45.957: E/AndroidRuntime(13131):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2850)
>   01-22 23:22:45.957: E/AndroidRuntime(13131):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2856)
>   01-22 23:22:45.957: E/AndroidRuntime(13131):    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:13166)
>   01-22 23:22:45.957: E/AndroidRuntime(13131):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:425)
>   ...

How do I assign an new Adapter to the `ViewPager` without crashing the app?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783571/android-viewpager-change-adapter

Edit: I see this is from one year ago.

Answer (score 2):

Use getFragmentManager() instead of getChildFragmentManager().

Answer (score 1):

Have you check this thread ?
[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragement no longer exists for key f1: index 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756102/java-lang-illegalstateexception-fragement-no-longer-exists-for-key-f1-index-3)
. Use `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` if you dont care about the Fragment's state restoring when you app go back from background.